# Landscape cannot be added "HTTP 410 Error Gone" to MAAS

Tags: maas, landscape

my virtual lab:

- 1 VM Ubuntu 16.04.1Lts for MAAS
- 1 VM Ubuntu 16.04.1Lts for Landscape
- 5 VM Ubuntu 16.04.1Lts for Openstack

I've added and upgraded MAAS and Landscape used their ppa stable. After to deploy Ubuntu 16.04 to node called Landscape

[image]

installed Landscape on that node

[image]

At the end I've obtained our Landscape installed. But when I try to register the node of MAAS received that error

[image]
[image]

with 5240 port

[image]
[image]

any suggest? thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to specify the port when trying to register MAAS if it's not listening on port 80, which it seems to be on 5240.

Comment: same issue, I've upgraded the post added new screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the same problem, found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape/+bug/1592994

Seems we can give up at this point till they support MAAS 2.0

Comment: yes, at this point we need to wait. The only thing is: why someone publish on Internet the guide to realise that when it's impossible to make... have a look  here (http://conjure-up.io/) and here at the end the page (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud).